# BASH solution to embedded read -p within a while read loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I know this has probably been asked in various ways on this forum, and around the web, but I have tried all methods to no avail. I have a while read loop with a "read -p" contained in an if statement within it. I understand that the standard input is the .txt file being pumped into the while loop, so read-p can't be piped to user input. What will be my recourse here. Please take a look at the code.

```
while read orasid1
do
if [ "$prompt1" = "yes" ]; then
read -p "Do you want to change the password for $username on $orasid (y/n)?" Yesno2

    case ${Yesno2:0:1} in
            y|Y )

    echo "Yes"
#Call SQL script here
    ;;
    * )
    "No"
    ;;
    esac

else

exit 16

fi

done < $log_dir/pwd_change_$server.txt
```

I'll appreciate whatever help anyone can give.

Comment: Don't use standard input for the outer loop. Use an alternate fd instead. Or open an fd to the tty and use that fd in the inner read.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different file handle for the outer read:

```
while read -u 3 orasid1; do
    ...
done 3< "$log_dir/pwd_change_$server.txt"
```

This is useful for any command (not just `read`) inside the body of the loop which might read (necessarily or not) from standard input.

You are still free to redirect standard input for the script as a whole from another file, for instance if you want to store canned responses to the various prompts in a file.